# excel funny table syntax

Tags: excel

what does this do?

```
=TABLE(,B5)
```

there is a table on the chart where every cell has a different value but in the formula it has that syntax above. every cell in the table has =TABLE(,B5) in it.

Comment: It gives an error: `That function is not valid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TABLE() is used for scenarios via [Data Tables](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/data-tables.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not a valid builtin function, it must be a user-defined function.

Comment: lllllllllllllll: Type Alt+F12